# What is the meaning of version number of java browser plugins?

Tags: java, java-deployment-toolkit

What is the meaning of version number of java browser plugins Java Deployment Toolkit and the Java Platform plugin?

Example: https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/attachment/160564/160564_toolkit.png

I get the `SE 7 U79` as described in [JEP223](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223) but not the `10.79.2.5` and neither the `7.0.790.15`; it looks like different notation of the 7u79 but I don't see it documented.

The documentation on the DT:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/ria_development.html#BABBCDDE
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html

was not much help neither. I don't even exactly get how the DT gets into browser plugins since it seems like it is just a bunch of javascript functions to include, not install as plugin.

Comment: I think `15` in `7.0.790.15` is the build number. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u79-relnotes-2494161.html

Comment: With the `7.0.790.15` I find the `790` inconsitent with the `79` in `7U79`